# Bulk adding cm-devices to collection: cannot bind to parameter resourceid because it is null

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to bulk add a txt list of hostnames to a collection in SCCM.

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\hostnames.txt" | foreach { Add-CMDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRule -CollectionName "XXXXX" -ResourceID (Get-CMDevice -Name $_).ResourceID }
```

However, I keep getting the error cannot bind to parameter resourceID. When running the get-content part only, the hostnames appear. When running (get-cmdevice -name XXXXX).resourceID no errors, but the combination seems to fail.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Add-CMDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRule : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ResourceId' because it is null.
At line:1 char:167
+ ... t XXXXX" -ResourceID (Get-CMDevice -Name $_).ResourceID }
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-CMDeviceCol...tMembershipRule], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Coll 
   ections.Commands.AddDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRuleCommand

Comment: Even when I try without txt, I just enter everything after foreach, and give a hostname instead of $_, it's still giving me the same error: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ResourceId' because it is null? The hostname exists in SCCM, doublechecked that. No issue with the collection, also tried with collectionid.

Comment: Does `Get-CMDevice` work at all?

Comment: When using get-cmdevice with resourceID, it seems to be working, but not with name

Comment: Very strange, we are with 3, all 3 CM12 admins and only 1 of us 3 can use get-cmdevice with -name, me and the other guy only with -resourceid